# Conditional formatting the NumberFormat

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

When "Value" is selected from a dropdown in column A, I want the NumberFormat of the corresponding cell in column B to change to `"#,##0.00"`. In all other cases (including if "Value" is later deleted from the cell in column A) I want column B to be formatted as text.

I tried using `FormatConditions` and couldn't get it to work. I've tried asking ChatGPT, which suggested using a worksheet change event. It drafted the code below which worked... but only worked once, and has never worked again, even when I've tried starting from scratch in a new file to try again.

There's no error message, just nothing happens to column B when I type "Value" in any cell of column A.

How do I get this to work consistently? Should I be using conditional formatting or worksheet change events like this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim changedCell As Range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    
    Set dataRange = Me.Range("A2:B" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) ' Assuming data starts from row 2
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is in the first column of the data range
    If Not Intersect(Target, dataRange.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable event handling to avoid triggering another change event
        
        For Each changedCell In Intersect(Target, dataRange.Columns(1))
            ' Check if the value in the changed cell is "Value"
            If changedCell.Value = "Value" Then
                ' Update the format of the corresponding cell in the second column
                changedCell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            End If
        Next changedCell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable event handling
    End If
End Sub
```

It's Office 365 (Excel version 2208).

Comment: Does Excel recognize the data in Column B as numeric? If it sees numbers as text, assigning a numeric format will have no effect.

Comment: @RichardCook, yes I think this is the problem. If the numbers were entered when the format was set to number then it works and will change, if they were entered when it was set to text then it won't. The problem is the same if you manually change the format to number for a string of digits entered as text. Is there a workaround?

Comment: See my answer for the workaround.

Comment: @CLR Ah sorry, I saw the alternative for the IF statement in your answer, but hadn't spotted you'd also addressed this issue. Thank you! The input text is subject to data validation so no need to make it case insensitive.

Comment: You're not going mad. I only added the additional IF when I read Richard's comments.

Answer (score 1):

The IF statement should have an alternative. Your code can only change formatting to the numeric format and will not set to text if changed. Also, if the cell format is text, you need to force numbers input as text back to numeric inputs.

Try:

```
If changedCell.Value = "Value" Then
    ' Update the format of the corresponding cell in the second column
    changedCell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    If IsNumeric(changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Else
    changedCell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
End If
```

You may want to consider making the test case insensitive.. it depends how you're populating column A.